# Как в C# объявить метод, у которого один из типов (параметров) является internal и доступен только через рефлексию?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Нужно для одного "хака", чтобы унаследовать то, что вообще-то не предусмотрено для кастомаизации.

Собственно, нужно унаследовать один абстрактный класс из WPF/

(что именно делать - я знаю. Пользуюсь и рефлектором, и утилитой покруче.)

Но проблема в том, что несколько его методов нужно в своем наследнике переопределить (override), разумеется переопределить нужно с правильными параметрами, но эти параметры имеют типы, которые являются internal и недоступны из вне - не скомпилируется.

Если бы нужно было просто вызвать такой тип (в смысле создать экземпляр и т.д.), то я бы применил рефлексию.

Но как объявить метод с параметром такого типа? object же не катит.

Нужно как-то *динамически создать метод*. Но как это делается.

Comment: Боюсь, не получится. Вы не сможете инстанциировать internal-тип другой сборки, рефлексия бросит исключение.

Comment: Кроме того, при override вам нужен метод с точно такой же сигнатурой. Иначе снова-таки класс не создастся.

Comment: @VladD, а каким-нибудь `Reflection.Emit` не получится впихнуть новый класс в сборку, тогда ограничение на одну сборку будет соблюдено?

Comment: @Grundy: Не-а. Иначе было бы слишком просто обходить защиту. Создавать классы можно только в _новой_ сборке. (Я пробовал, и кстати с [примерно такими же целями](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18193122/276994), как и ТС.)

Comment: @VladD ну не такая уж это и защита, не деньги же там лежат) Как-то по-любому можно в ОЗУ изменить то, что загружено. А учитывая, что я реверс-инженер - мне это рано или поздно все равно понадобится. Но в нынешнем проекте и так столько гемора... Я его один делаю и вообще никто не мотивирует, ибо никому больше толком не нужно, клиентов тоже не намечено, как раскручивать буду толком не знаю, зато ругают (спам-ботоводов) всем народом...

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Такая-такая, на этом основана модель безопасности .NET. Например, если вы грузите чужую сборку без прав на нативный код, то она не может нарушить защиту.

Comment: @koshkashoshka Что конкретно вы хотели сделать? Может, есть нормальный способ?

Comment: @Squidward Вы с андроидом дело имели? Что такое 9-patch знаете? Вот хочу кастомную Brush такого плана для WPF сделать. Назову NinePatchBrush. Да, способ обойтись без своей Brush есть (так и начну делать сейчас), но лучше, чтобы это была именно кастомная Brush - на будущее будет удобнее. Более того, думаю, если на гитхаб выложить с нормальным описанием - будут пользоваться классом.. См. предыдущий мой вопрос.

Comment: @VladD Насчет невозможности создать экземпляр internal-класса вы ошибаетесь - через рефлексию удалось создать его и вызвать его public-метод. А вот унаследовать класс, в котором хоть 1 абстрактный метод в сигнатуре содержит internal-типы - нельзя: не скомпилируется.

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Странно, можно код?

Comment: @VladD Класс в сборке ClassLibrary1.dll: https://pastebin.com/6JJKbvkx Вызов: https://pastebin.com/N3qhnh6m Сборку загружаю динамически, будет ли работать без этого - не знаю.

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Хм, и правда :-) А можно сигнатуру метода, который вы хотите перекрыть? Мне интересны в первую очередь все модификаторы доступа (private/protected/internal/public).

Comment: @VladD Попробуйте в приложении WPF унаследовать Brush или TileBrush, увидите

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно в той форме, в какой вы хотите. Вам придётся искать другую стратегию.

Пускай у вас в недоступной вам сборке есть абстрактный внутренний (`internal`) метод. Для того, чтобы создать метод, необходимо определить *новую* сборку. Но при этом вы будете перекрывать метод, который *не виден* из вашей новой сборки.

А это запрещено. При попытке сгенерировать такой метод рефлексия честно отказала (мне):

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'Do' on type 'DerivedType' from assembly 'Dynamic, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is overriding a method that is not visible from that assembly.'

---

Для тех, кто хочет поэкспериментировать, вот <del>игровая площадка</del> тестовый код:

В отдельной сборке:

```
// базовый класс
public abstract class PublicClass
{
    public void Run() => Do("Hello world");
    internal abstract void Do(string s);
}

// референсная имплементация, здесь можно подсматривать IL-код
public class ValidDerivedClass : PublicClass
{
    internal override void Do(string s) => Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

И в тестовом проекте:

```
var baseAsm = Assembly.Load("ReflectionTestLib"); // грузим ту самую сборку
var baseType = baseAsm.GetType("ReflectionTestLib.PublicClass");
var newasm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        new AssemblyName("Dynamic"),
        AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var modb = newasm.DefineDynamicModule("Module", "Dynamic.dll");
var typeb = modb.DefineType("DerivedType", TypeAttributes.Public, parent: baseType);
var methodb = typeb.DefineMethod(
        "Do",
        MethodAttributes.Assembly | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
        typeof(void),
        new[] { typeof(string) });
var il = methodb.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) }));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Type newType = typeb.CreateType(); // здесь происходит исключение
// но если поменять модификатор на public (и MethodAttributes.Assembly
// на MethodAttributes.Public), то код запустится
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);
newType.GetMethod("Run").Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

---

Вероятно, обойти защиту можно грязными трюками наподобие редактирования в памяти управляющих структур через нативный или unsafe-код. Просто не делайте так никогда.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67650/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---c-------).